# Assembly: Define empty 2D array 32bit (NASM + Intel syntax)

Tags: linux, assembly, multidimensional-array, nasm, intel-syntax

**How can we define empty 2D array 251x256 for 32 bit code in assembly?**

I have an old example in 16 bit code for assembly:

```
DataIn          byte    251 dup (256 dup (?))
```

Now I would like to declare the same thing but that will work for 32 bit architectures for NASM.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I did before and it's not working properly. I think that the link you posted has only code in 16 bits.

Comment: I would declare `array resb 16` and access it as two dimensional, for example, as 4x4 (for example), or 8x2.

Comment: This is your second attempts, the first one [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100788/assembly-defining-input-and-output-of-the-code-nasm-intel-syntax). Have you attempted to solve the problem? What is the memory layout of a 251x256 byte array? How many space `251 DUP(?)` reserves? and what about `251 DUP (256 DUP (?))`? Can you do it with the `TIMES` directive (as already suggested)? Hint: Yes

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez If I do this in my case, I will get 64 256 values in a normal array. It will be quite hard to make everything work in the correct way. But if I won't find anything easier to implement, I will use your answer. So thank you

Comment: That's a lot of memory.

Comment: @MargaretBloom In the previous question I was working with how to define Input files. And since I solved that problem I am working with the next one. How to define 2D array.... + I will try to take your "hint" in considoration. So thank you for the help... I am trying to learn all the things. But I have never worked with an assembly before so I am working on a huge project and trying to learn as fast as I can.

Comment: @io16 There are neither "normal" arrays nor arrays in assembly. Just buffers. You should check how 2D arrays are laid out in memory, i.e. as a continuous sequence of bytes. 64'256 is the correct size if there is no padding (and there shouldn't be any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a one dimensional array and access it as two dimensional by calculating the offset of each row and adding the column. In your case, your array is 251 rows and 256 columns, so you can multiply 256 by the desired row and add the column, example :

```
section .data
    array  resb  251*256  ;251 ROWS X 256 COLUMNS.
_start:
    mov eax,256     ;ROW SIZE (256 COLUMNS PER ROW).
    mov ebx,35      ;DESIRED ROW (35).
    mul ebx         ;EAX * EBX = 8960.

    mov esi,array   ;POINT TO ARRAY.
    add esi,eax     ;POINT TO DESIRED ROW (35).
    add esi,20      ;POINT TO DESIRED COLUMN (20).
```

This is for type byte, for bigger types it will be necessary to multiply by the size (by 2, by 4, etc).

Answer (score 0):

From all the help in the comments I think I figured it out.

**1. There is no such things as 2D arrays in assembly**

```
2 4 6 
3 6 9 
7 8 9
```

Are located in memory like this: 2 4 6 3 6 9 7 8 9

**2. So the only way to create "2D" array is to improvise.**

**3. We can keep 2 counters that will keep track of our improvised 2D array.**

**4. So for every 3 numbers we will increase the counter for rows and we will "move" to the next improvised row.**